# Handling ASP.Net framework exceptions thrown by dependencies

Tags: asp.net, exception, caching, azure, azure-web-roles

My Azure .Net web app uses a shared cache role which can sometimes throw an exception meaning, "retry later" if it is hot swapping. Currently, that causes my web app to error. However, this is thrown before my app has even started up since it is the framework/IIS which has attempted to setup the cache and failed.

How can I catch these exceptions and do something useful when redirecting to an error page would still require my app and config/cache to load, which would cause the exceptions again? Even if I could catch the exception in Application_Error, I don't think I can retry the connection to the cache because I didn't create it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Few questions :
Didn't clearly get your question. So it's your client calling cache, who is getting these errors right?
Are you using session state provider for cache? If not, When you said you are not making connections to the cache, what did you mean?
What is the exact error?
Is it intermittent? Is it always happening during role startup, the case u mentioned here?

Comment: It is my site using the cache as configured in web.config and using the DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider for Azure. The problem is that my app itself does not set this up, it happens automatically when my app starts up so if an exception occurs at this point, I can't handle it in the same way as if I was calling this setup from code. The exact exception is not important, nor is it important how often it is occurring. What is important is that exceptions sometimes occur and I want to handle them.